# WiredTiger prefix compression for index on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

According to the MongoDB documentation (at least this blog entry https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/new-compression-options-mongodb-30), prefix compression is enabled by default on MongoDB.

However, when I look at one collection, I see this:

```
db.myCollection.stats()
{
...,
    "wiredTiger" : {
        "metadata" : {
            "formatVersion" : 1
        },
        "creationString" : "...,prefix_compression=0,prefix_compression_min=4"
...
}
```

Does `prefix_compression=0` means that my indexes are not prefix-compressed ?

Comment: thank you for asking this question! I wondered the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default collection stats only include information on the collection data (which uses block-level compression rather than prefix compression).

To see index details you need to provide an additional [`indexDetails` option](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.stats/#db.collection.stats), eg:

```
db.myCollection.stats({indexDetails:true}).indexDetails._id_.creationString
```

You should see "prefix_compression=true" in the index `creationString` value.

Comment: thank you so much! I was confused like the OP was